# Is 'otherwise then' a correct construct?

Tags: meaning, phrases, ambiguity

I was reading a Stack Overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49592061/) and argued with the author that his wording is confusing, but now I'm not so sure if I'm right.

The phrase in question is:

> If a type `T` adopts the protocol and does not define `T.IndexDistance`
>   otherwise then `T.IndexDistance` becomes a type alias for `Int`

The author initially had it written as 'otherwise, then', later removed the comma. Still to me it doesn't make sense.

To me it seems you have to either of these:

- otherwise, xyz
- otherwise, the
- then

'otherwise then' is just redundant. It's like making two right turns when you need one.

Comment: Is there a comma missing?

Comment: can you see my edit?

Comment: I'd retain the comma to make for easier parsing. // There were once many arguments of the form 'If, then, therefore' (If A is true, it follows that B and then C are also true) (at least in teaching in the UK): so many that the name stuck. Obviously,  there doesn't usually _need_ to be a 'then' in 'If A is true, then B is true'. But redundancy isn't wrong per se, and I'd say that including it here is another aid to readability.

Comment: You could just move the *otherwise*:  If a type T adopts the protocol and does not *otherwise* define T.IndexDistance then ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is not about programming language.

Comment: @user9825893y50932 Everyone has their vote, but to me that's absurd. I'm just asking whether or not 'otherwise then' is a correct construct. The context of it can be anything. In my case it was programming language.

Comment: Redundany is not necessarily an "error". It is often used for emphasis. People dont have to write in ways that others (read: *you*) are logically correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you interpreted the answer as "other than", as in "a number other than 0". However, I think the author meant that "`T.IndexDistance` becomes a type alias for `Int` unless `T.IndexDistance` is defined otherwise". The author was therefore correct in his original wording, and the critical comma should not have been removed.

That being said, a usage of "otherwise then" as a comparison is incorrect for several reasons:

- *th**e**n* is an adverb meaning *at that time*, *afterwards*, *therefore* (OED). The correct word for a comparison would be the preposition *th**a**n*;
- *otherwise than* is, as you said, redundant;
- such a usage would not make sense in the given context, as one cannot "define `T.IndexDistance` differently than `T.IndexDistance`".